# How to fix responsive columns on this website?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I'm trying to figure out a way to make this work using CSS. I use wordpress and a theme so I can't really change much of the markup so I'm trying to solve this problem with CSS first.

I'm building a site with 3 columns article. It's working fine on desktop but when you start resizing. It goes like this.

[image]

What I want is that 'First post from Salon87 Brooklyn' should be next to 'Second Post' like this.

[image]

And this is what I want it to look like on desktop

[image]

Here's the code. http://www.salon87.nyc/news/

Comment: Why is this off-topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the HTML is that, there is an element `fix` added to the blocks. You need to hide it for mobile devices. Try changing 991px to your requirement.

**CSS**

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .fix {
    display: none;
  }
}
```